# Finding $J$ such that this diagram commutes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, lie-groups, quaternions

DISCLAIMER: This is not homework.

I did this exercise here and need someone to check if my work is correct:

Is it possible to find a matrix $J\in M_{2n}(\mathbb C)$ such that the following diagram commutes?

$$\begin{array}
\mathbb \mathbb H^n & \stackrel{g_n}{\longrightarrow} & \mathbb C^{2n} \\
\downarrow{ j} & & \downarrow{R_J} \\
\mathbb H^n & \stackrel{g_n}{\longrightarrow} & \mathbb C^{2n}  
\end{array}
$$

from [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=Un_15Im3NhUC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false). The down arrow $j$ is multiplication by the unit quaternion $j$. Since the books convention is to use left scalar multiplication this is $jX$ for $X\in \mathbb H^n$. The map $R_J$ on the other hand is right multiplication by $J$: $R_J(X) = XJ$.

Let's assume that the map $g_n$ is $(a_1 + b_1j, a_2 + b_2 j, \dots) \mapsto (a_1, a_2, \dots, b_1, b_2, \dots)$.

---

My work:

I let

$J_{2n} = \rho_n (jI) = \left ( 
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & I \\
-I & 0
\end{array}\right ) $ where $\rho_n$ is the inclusion homomorphism $M_n(\mathbb H) \hookrightarrow M_{2n}(\mathbb C)$. Then

$$g_n(j(X + Yj)) = g_n(\overline{X}j + \overline{Y}j^2 = (-\overline{Y}, \overline{X})$$ and

$$ R_J(g_n(X + Yj)) = R_J((X,Y)) = (-Y,X)$$

so the diagram for this $J$ does not commute. (Note that if left multiplication by $j$ is replaced by right multiplication then the diagram commutes. )

I want to argue that this diagram commutes *for no $J$*. But how do I do this? I tried to let $J$ be arbitrary and consider the $n$-vector consisting of $i$. I denote it $i \in \mathbb C^n$ and I denote the (left) multiplication from the diagram by $L_j$. I think that

$$ L_j(i) = -k$$
 and

$$ g_n^{-1}\circ R_J \circ g_n (i) = k$$

but even though $g_n (i) =i$ is clear to me I am stuck showing $R_J(i)= k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your $g_n$ is invertible, so if such a $J$ exists then it should satisfy
$$R_J(x)=(g_n\circ j\circ g_n^{-1})(x),$$
for every $x\in\Bbb{C}^{2n}$. Writing $x=(a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_n)$, we can simply write out what the right-hand side is. As this is homework, I'll leave omit the tedious details, but you'll find
$$(g_n\circ j\circ g_n^{-1})(x)=(-\overline{b_1},\ldots,-\overline{b_n},\overline{a_1},\ldots,\overline{a_n}),$$
where $\overline{z}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $z\in\Bbb{C}$. This is the composition of the map
$$\Bbb{C}^{2n}\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{C}^{2n}:\ (a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_n)\ \longmapsto\ (-b_1,\ldots,-b_n,a_1,\ldots,a_n),$$
which is linear and invertible, with coordinatewise complex conjugation, which is not linear (over $\Bbb{C}$!). It follows that $R_J$ is not linear, a contradiction, meaning that no matrix $J\in M_{2n}(\Bbb{C})$ making the diagram commute exists.

Comment: This is not homework. I am doing exercise in a book i am reading.

Comment: Ok, I see how you get the conjugates. But how is it the composition of the map $(a,b) \mapsto (-b,a)$?

Comment: It's composition of the map $(a,b)\mapsto (-b, a)$ with the map $(c_i)\mapsto (\bar{c_i})$ - componentwise complex conjugation.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki lol see my comment to the other answer ;D sorry and thank you for your help!